# How to get input value in functional component in react.js? (TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add data to Cloud Firestore but I am getting this error on Button Click

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined
```

here are the code.

```
    function Note(props) {

      function ReplyAnswer(e)
      {

        var date = moment().utcOffset('+05:30').format('hh:mm A DD-MM-YYYY');

        firebase.firestore().collection('qna2dreply').add(
            {
                rcontent: e.target.value,
                replyby: userName,
                replybyid: userID,
                replytoid: props.id,
                time: new Date(),
                time2: date
            })
            .then(() => {
                document.getElementById('xxx').value = '';
                swal("Successfully Replied to "+props.title);
            });
      }


      return (
        <div>
        <div className="note">
          <h1>{props.title} <span className="time"> {(props.time).toString()}</span></h1>
          <p>{props.content} 
             <input 
             className="replyForminput" 
             name="content" 
             required 
             placeholder={'Reply to '+props.title} 
             autoCorrect="off" 
             autoComplete="off" /> 

             <button onClick={() => { ReplyAnswer() }} 
              className="replyBtn"> Reply </button></p>
              {props.id == idx ? (<div><RBox /></div>) : null}
        </div>
        </div>
      );
      }
```

Please Help

..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

**First - for `e` is `undefined`:**

You should only pass the `ReplyAnswer` to the `onClick` event of the `button`, don't wrap it in an arrow function:

```
<button onClick={ReplyAnswer} className="replyBtn"> Reply </button>
```

This will pass the event object to your `ReplyAnswer` as an `e` parameter. If you wrap your `ReplyAnswer` in an arrow function, and call it without passing any parameter to it, like what you have done:

```
() => { ReplyAnswer() }
```

You can see that `ReplyAnswer` receives no parameter, so your `e` is `undefined`. Your arrow function is also a zero-parameter function, so it will not receive event object from `onClick` event.

**Second - for `e.target.value` is `null`:**

Because you are calling `ReplyAnswer` in the `onClick` event of the `button` so the `e.target.value` is `null`.

To solve this, you can wrap your `input` and `button` inside a `form`, like this:

```
<form onSubmit={ReplyAnswer}>
  <input 
    className="replyForminput" 
    name="content" 
    required 
    placeholder={'Reply to '+props.title} 
    autoCorrect="off" 
    autoComplete="off" /> 
  <button type="submit" className="replyBtn"> Reply </button>
</form>
```

Add `type="submit"` to your `button` and move your `ReplyAnswer` from `onClick` event of the `button` to `onSubmit` event of the `form`. Remember to add `name` property of the input, too.

Then in your `ReplyAnswer`, do this:

```
function ReplyAnswer(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = new FormData(e.target);
  var rcontent = data.get("content"); // your input `name` property is `content`

  var date = moment().utcOffset('+05:30').format('hh:mm A DD-MM-YYYY');
  firebase.firestore().collection('qna2dreply').add({
    rcontent,
    replyby: userName,
    replybyid: userID,
    replytoid: props.id,
    time: new Date(),
    time2: date
  }).then(() => {
    document.getElementById('xxx').value = '';
    swal("Successfully Replied to "+props.title);
  });
}
```

The `FormData` interface provides a way to easily construct a set of key/value pairs representing form fields and their values. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData.

Comment: Error is gone, but still  `rcontent: e.target.value` is null

Comment: Because `e.target` is your button, not your input, so its value is null.

Comment: SO, How to fix it? I want Input value on button click.

Comment: but `document.getElementById('xxx').value = '';` this is not resetting the input field. How to reset once submit is done?

Comment: That because your `input` doesn't have any `id` property so `document.getElementById('xxx')` will be `undefined` or the other element.

Answer (score 0):

e.target.value is undefined because the event (e) isn't being passed through from the event handler (ReplyAnswer).

Simply Change: button onClick={() => **{** ReplyAnswer() **}**}

To:            button onClick={(**e**) =>  ReplyAnswer(**e**) }

This ensures event passed properly. Notice the curly braces removed to prevent returning undefined from click handler.

Cheers,

Comment: Error is gone, but still  `rcontent: e.target.value` is null

Comment: Is it an async event? Either way --- the event is now passing (good) but it's null? Why? Because it's a synthetic event and is getting emptied for use unless you explicitly add e.persist() at the top of the ReplyAnswer function

Comment: Try adding the e.persist() and let us know if that does that trick.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function ReplyAnswer(value)
      {

        var date = moment().utcOffset('+05:30').format('hh:mm A DD-MM-YYYY');

        firebase.firestore().collection('qna2dreply').add(
            {
                rcontent:value,
                replyby: userName,
                replybyid: userID,
                replytoid: props.id,
                time: new Date(),
                time2: date
            })
            .then(() => {
                document.getElementById('xxx').value = '';
                swal("Successfully Replied to "+props.title);
            });
      }
```

```html
1.add an id attribute in your input element eg:<input type="text" id="your_field_id" value="hellow"/>
2. Write your action button like this : <button onClick={(e)=>ReplyAnswer(document.getElementById("your_field_id").value)}>Click</button> 



3. You can use REFDOM follow this link
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html
```